# How to say, "I was so young once!"

Tags: expressions

I was watching *Hiroshima mon amour* and heard the phrase, "I was so young once," at a pivotal moment and would like to reference it, but can't phonetically reproduce the spelling–thanks you in advance. Also, can the phrase "so young once" be cut from the complete phrase without any grammatical error?

Comment: Can you say at what point on the track you heard it it will be easier to find.

Comment: Min 52:14 --Criterion Collection

Comment: Have I missed something here?

Comment: I'm not sure what this question has to do with French, as the sentence you heard seems to be in English, and the OP doesn't ask for a translation or anything.

Answer (score 6):

The precise statement in *Hiroshima mon amour* is :

> Ah! que j'ai été jeune un jour.

Extracting *jeune un jour* alone would be grammatically acceptable as a nominal sentence.

Answer (score -2):

C’est plus de mon âge ces conneries.

Comme l’a fait remarqué @Stéphane Gimenez ce n’est pas vraiment la traduction de "I was so young once", ce serait plutôt : "I'm not young enough anymore for this shit"…

Comment: Une explication serait la bienvenue. Ça ne marche que dans des contextes très particuliers…

Comment: La question posée est relative à une réplique précise du film *Hiroshima mon amour*, elle ne demande pas une (re)traduction de son sous-titre.

Comment: @jilliagre C’est vraiment le sous-titre de ce livre ?

Comment: C'est un film, on sous-titre rarement les livres. Il s'agit de la phrase prononcée dans la version anglaise et très probablement aussi de son sous-titre. https://www.criterion.com/current/posts/4140-muriel-or-the-time-of-return-ashes-of-time

Comment: Il suffit de lire la question pour comprendre qu'elle porte sur le [film](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiroshima_mon_amour) (→ *heard*, *timing on track*) et [non sur le livre](http://www.marguerite-duras.com/Hiroshima-mon-amour.php). Et même si tu comprends mal la question ce que tu as écrit ne se trouve pas dans le livre (écrit d'après le film et pas le script du film), c'est facile à vérifier.